# How to fetch content of pages having specific template?

Tags: bolt-cms

I want to fetch content of contenttype `pages` which are using a `template`  `page_with_sidebar.twig`?

How do I do that?

e.g

```
{% setcontent a = 'pages' [some filter here to retrieve specific templated pages] %}
```

Answer (score 2):

`{% setcontent side_pages = 'pages' where { template: 'page_with_sidebar.twig' } %}`